# gtkmm3 example not compiling (undefined reference)

Tags: c++, gtk3, gtkmm, linux-mint, cinnamon

I'm trying to compile following example

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app =
    Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv,
      "org.gtkmm.examples.base");

  Gtk::Window window;
  window.set_default_size(200, 200);

  return app->run(window);
}
```

i use this command: `g++ ./gtk.cpp -o ./gtk -Wall pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs` and get this error message:
`/usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.so: undefined reference to 'g_type_check_instance_is_fundamentally_a'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`
how can i fix it ?

Comment: I think you miss -l option, somethin like ``-lgtkmm``. I just can't find gtkmm3 binaries.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
g++ ./gtk.cpp -o ./gtk -Wall `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
```

You need to add ` before and after pkg-config command.

pkg-config gives you flags for compiler and they have to be passed as compiler parameter (Output of pkg-config but not same pkg-config command).

Adding **`** character cause *pkg-config* command output is added as parameter to compiler.

You can simply visualize this difference using echo:

```
$ echo pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs
pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs

$ echo `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
-pthread -I/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtkmm-3.0/include -I/usr/include/giomm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/giomm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0/unix-print -I/usr/include/gdkmm-3.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdkmm-3.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/glibmm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibmm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sigc++-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/atkmm-1.6 -I/usr/include/pangomm-1.4 -I/usr/lib/pangomm-1.4/include -I/usr/include/cairomm-1.0 -I/usr/lib/cairomm-1.0/include -lgtkmm-3.0 -latkmm-1.6 -lgdkmm-3.0 -lgiomm-2.4 -lpangomm-1.4 -lgtk-3 -lglibmm-2.4 -lcairomm-1.0 -lgdk-3 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lsigc-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

Comment: yes, i did that, i just didn't know how to escape them and insert into question

Comment: no it's not. i'm getting this error and have no idea why

Comment: make sure you have libatk installed in verson 1.0  *sudo apt-get install libatk1.0*

Comment: What distro (and version) is this?

Comment: @murrayc it's Mint 17.1 "Rebecca" - Cinnamon (32-bit)

Comment: Where is the library? Try to find it: *locate libatk-1.0* and then *sudo ln -f -s /usr/path_where_it_is_located /usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.so*

Comment: Tony, then this looks like a problem with the Mint package. I suggest that you try a simple GTK+ C hello world program too.

Comment: @jmmk _locate libatk-1.0_ output : _/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so_
_/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0_
_/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0.21009.1_
_/usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.la_
_/usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.so_
_/usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.so.0_
_/usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.so.0.21512.1_

Comment: @murrayc compiling simple [GTK+ C example](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html) give me the same error: _/usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.so: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_is_fundamentally_a'_

Comment: @Tony Then it looks like a problem with the GTK+ (or atk) package on Mint. I suggest that you report it to Mint. It does seem strange that such a fundamental package would be broken, but I guess the Mint packagers would be the best people to help with it.